# Javascript filter by nested object attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array:

```
arr = [{id: 1, type: {name: "Approval", id: 1}},
       {id: 2, type: {name: "Rejection", id: 2}},
       {id: 3, type: {name: "Approval", id: 1}}
      ];
```

Why does the following produce and [] result? I would expect to get an array of 2 objects (i.e. id 1 and 3).

```
$.grep(arr, function(a) { return a.type.name === "Approval"; })
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Please post the actual code, since that has a syntax error so it won't run at all.

Comment: If you fix the code, i.e, close all the objects inside the array, and fix the return statement inside the grep as `return a.type.name === "Approval"`, it works as expected.

Comment: You are correct @Shidersz. It was a syntax error. The code now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use jQuery here? Javascript gives you perfect methods for that. [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const arr = [
{id: 1, type: {name: "Approval", id: 1}},
{id: 2, type: {name: "Rejection", id: 2}},
{id: 3, type: {name: "Approval", id: 1}}
];
      
const matches = arr
    .filter(entry => entry.type.name === 'Approval')
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: The jQuery code will run in old browsers that don't have `filter` and `find`.

Comment: I need to have IE compatibility, and so we are stuck not using filter and find.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is a reserved keyword in js. Hence you cannot use it as a variable and access its properties.

Instead, you need to access the properties of the `a` variable:

```js
$.grep(arr, function(a) { return a.type.name === "Approval"; })
```

Comment: It must have been a copying error, since the code would have gotten a syntax error, not return `[]`.

Comment: Correct. I have edited the original code. Sorry for the confusion.